# Mixing forms authenication and Office 365 authentication in one ASP.NET web site

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication, integration, office365

We have a large line of business internet application written in ASP.NET that uses forms authentication.  The  application is used heavily by internal people as well as several thousand external clients and suppliers.

Recently we have rolled out Office 365 throughout the organisation.

Currently the Office 365 world and the line of business world do not talk and we are aiming to integrate them more closely together.

At a minimum we want to authenticate against Office 365 rather than forms authentication for internal users.  In this way we are effectively logged into both systems and hyperlinks between both systems will work without the need for the user to have to log in again.

Authenticating against Visual Studio 2013 is now easy since it is now part of creating a new project and we have a good proof of concept application running.

The problem we face is with all external users.  We would prefer them to continue to use the forms authentication mechanism.

The problem is that both mechanisms appear to be exclusive of one another.

In the most trivial and obvious example of where they don't want to play together is that forms authentication requires the web.config to be set as

```
<authentication mode="Forms"/>
```

yet Office 365 authentications requires it to be set as

```
<authentication mode="None">
```

How do we go about solving this problem?  Is it simply of matter of some web.config setting wizardry that we yet to find?  Or do we need to some more drastic re-engineering of our architecture?

We have attempted the following

Having a Office 365 login page in a different directory to that of a forms authentication log in page and have either a separate web.config in each directory or make use of the "Locations" attribute in the root web.config.   This does not work since either one authentication technique always jumps in front of the other or the various settings are just not allowed in sub directories.

We have considered the following:

Having two web applications; one for internal people and one for everyone else. Internal people would be login into a different domain. We really don't want to do this since it will lead to 'hyperlink hell', it will make deployment more difficult and will cause havoc with our database level caching that forms part of our ORM.

We could move all users over to the active directory and everyone authenticates against it.  I would be a little concerned about the user's log on experience in this case since it will be vastly different to their current experience and the cost of the Azure Active directory will become non trivial.

Anyone got any big ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got to talk to a Microsoft person at TechEd.  They said that in Q1 of 2015, you will be able to upload any number of people into azure AD (for free or very cheaply) and then they could log on just like internal people. This person then said, hang on, I wasn't supposed to tell you that yet!  So watch out for MS announcements next year on this topic.